# Unable to locate package libglut3-dev

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management

I was not able to download the software `libglut3-dev` in my Ubuntu 12.04.2
I was behind a proxy. I was getting the following error.

```
sudo apt-get install libxi-dev libxmu-dev libglut3-dev
[sudo] password for sai: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libglut3-dev
```

I changed the sources.list file, but it remains the same. How can I install this package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package libglut3-dev is available for Ubuntu 10.04 in the Ubuntu Software Center, but it is not available in the USC in Ubuntu 12.04. The closest matches to libglut3-dev in Ubuntu 12.04 are freeglut3 and freeglut3-dev. The freeglut3 package is also called OpenGL Utility Toolkit. The freeglut3-dev package is also called OpenGL Utility Toolkit development files. GLUT is a window system independent toolkit for writing OpenGL programs, implementing a simple windowing API, which makes learning about and exploring OpenGL programming very easy.

<sup>**Reference:** https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+source/libfreenect/+changelog</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate the package using Synaptic Package Manager, which you can install by typing `sudo apt-get install synaptic` in a terminal window.